# node-red call node function from nodes, like call common function

Tags: function, node-red

I have 2 nodes, which needs to call one function - it's common place in programming.

I suppose, there is no way in node-red to call the function, except "wiring" Function nodes sequentially.

Well, I did try it, but with no success.

Please look(copy_paste) at my flow and give help:

```
[{"id":"d86b4b3b.0670d8","type":"inject","z":"901492e5.e9666","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":169,"y":224,"wires":[["1a6b10c8.0788cf"]]},{"id":"1a6b10c8.0788cf","type":"function","z":"901492e5.e9666","name":"func0","func":"if(msg.payload.second_call){return [null,msg];}\nelse {msg.payload[\"second_call\"] = true;\nmsg.payload[\"count\"] = 0;\nreturn [msg,null];\n}\n","outputs":"2","noerr":0,"x":350,"y":223,"wires":[["577ae7e1.0c1948"],["b2204e3f.44cef"]]},{"id":"577ae7e1.0c1948","type":"function","z":"901492e5.e9666","name":"func1","func":"msg.payload.count++;\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":352,"y":316,"wires":[["1a6b10c8.0788cf"]]},{"id":"4e8f3348.10ab0c","type":"debug","z":"901492e5.e9666","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"payload","x":783.5,"y":332,"wires":[]},{"id":"b2204e3f.44cef","type":"function","z":"901492e5.e9666","name":"func3","func":"msg.payload.count++;\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":619,"y":332,"wires":[["4e8f3348.10ab0c"]]},{"id":"5bf50c74.5376e4","type":"inject","z":"901492e5.e9666","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":160,"y":422,"wires":[["c9b5e6b.ae91818"]]},{"id":"c9b5e6b.ae91818","type":"function","z":"901492e5.e9666","name":"func10","func":"if(msg.payload.second_call){return [null,msg];}\nelse {msg.payload[\"second_call\"] = true;\nmsg.payload[\"count\"] = 0;\nreturn [msg,null];\n}\n","outputs":"2","noerr":0,"x":345,"y":422,"wires":[["f11eb781.083348"],["b2204e3f.44cef"]]},{"id":"f11eb781.083348","type":"function","z":"901492e5.e9666","name":"func11","func":"msg.payload.count+=10;\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":348,"y":508,"wires":[["c9b5e6b.ae91818"]]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few of options here.

1. If you are going to use the "function" multiple time then you could wrap it up in a sub-flow. This means that there is one copy of the code to edit and you can chain this into flows that do not have a common end.
2. If you are not going to have to change the "function" at all once it's written you can add it to the `functionGlobalContext` in the `settings.js`. This will let you include it in a given function node. See the [doc](https://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions#storing-data) for how to use the context. This does mean that you can't change the code without restarting Node-RED